# Use different assets folders for debug and release

Tags: android, gradle

This is my build.gradle for app, I want use 'assets/test1' as my debug assets folder and use 'assets/test2' as my release assets folder. I put a txt file test1.txt to 'asset/test1' and put a txt file test2.txt to 'asset/test2'. Somehow I find there is no test1.txt or test2.txt in build intermediates directory 'build\intermediates\assets\debug' or 'build\intermediates\assets\release'.
And there are 3 .ttf files in assets folder which I don't know where are they from.

-----------------------------------------------build.gralde----------------------------

```
sourceSets{
    main{
        assets.srcDir 'assets/common'
    }
    debug.assets.srcDirs = ['assets/test1']
    release.assets.srcDirs = ['assets/test2']
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        //assets.srcDirs = ['assets/test1']
    }
    debug{
        //assets.srcDirs = ['assets/test2']
    }
}
```

------------------------------------dir /s command------------------------------

```
 Volume in drive D is APP
 Volume Serial Number is 669E-F27F

 Directory of D:\code\PJShort\Test\app\build\intermediates\assets

16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          .
16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          ..
16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          debug
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of D:\code\PJShort\Test\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug

16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          .
16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          ..
16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          fonts
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of D:\code\PJShort\Test\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\fonts

16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          .
16/06/2017  06:24 p.m.    <DIR>          ..
13/06/2017  12:25 p.m.            32,303 helvetica.ttf
11/05/2017  02:29 p.m.             2,104 materialdrawerfont-font-v5.0.0.ttf
13/06/2017  12:25 p.m.           414,820 notosans.ttf
               3 File(s)        449,227 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)        449,227 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  36,491,513,856 bytes free
```

Comment: Is `debug` a source set? You have a `src/debug/assets` folder?

Comment: as you can see, debug and release are buildTypes.

Comment: app\build\intermediates\assets\debug folder is generated as it was shown in the result of dir /s command

Comment: Right, but you've also defined as sourcesets. Do the buildTypes go into sources like that? I've only seen flavors in sourcesets

Comment: app\build\intermediates\assets\debug was generated as the result of dos command dir /s shown

Comment: except assets, othertypes of sourcesets went very well. I only add a assets source folder.but the added assets cannot go intermediates when building.